# A word for neutral quality?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, terminology

A bad quality might be a 'sin' or 'flaw', and a good quality a 'grace' or 'virtue'. Is there a term like this for a neutral quality? If there is no term is there an idiom or slang?

Answer (score 1):

Nethawk,

I would note that the word quality is, itself, neutral:

> *quality*: an inherent feature : PROPERTY ([Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quality))

Other, similarly neutral, words that come to mind include:

> *attribute*: a quality, character, or characteristic ascribed to someone or something. ([Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attribute))

> *characteristic*: a distinguishing trait, quality, or property ([Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/characteristic))

> *trait*: an inherited characteristic ([Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trait))

and

> *feature*: a prominent part or characteristic ([Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feature))